# Raspberry : Forward Local Port To Multiple 4G Interfaces

Tags: tcp, interface, raspberry-pi, 4g

I have 2x4G LTE Modem connected by Ethernet to a Raspberry Pi (let's say eth0 & eth1)

What I would like to do is use this Raspberry Pi to forward a TCP traffic to a specific interface:

- Open the 127.0.0.1:3100 and use the eth0 interface
- Open the 127.0.0.1:3200 and use the eth1 interface

An application using a proxy trough 127.0.0.1:3100 will have a different IP from the one using the Proxy at 127.0.0.1:3200

Can it be done ? I tried with Squid & Dante, open a Socket5 or HTTP Proxy but I couldn't successfully use one or another connection, always the default.